# AppEngine Python urlfetch() fails with 416 error, same query succeeds in a browser

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm dusting off an app that worked a few months ago. I've made no changes. Here's the code in question:

```
    result = urlfetch.fetch(
        url=url,
        deadline=TWENTY_SECONDS)
    if result.status_code != 200:  # pragma: no cover
        logging.error('urlfetch failed.')
        logging.error('result.status_code = %s' % result.status_code)
        logging.error('url =')
        logging.error(url)
```

Here's the output:

```
WARNING  2015-04-20 01:13:46,473 urlfetch_stub.py:118] No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
ERROR    2015-04-20 01:13:46,932 adminhandlers.py:84] urlfetch failed. url =
ERROR    2015-04-20 01:13:46,933 adminhandlers.py:85] http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select/?q=%2Bevent_date%3A%5BNOW%20TO%20NOW%2B1DAY%5D%0D%0A%2BancestorGeoDescriptions:%22New%20York%20Metro%22%0D%0A%2BstubhubDocumentType%3Aevent&version=2.2&start=0&rows=1&wt=json&fl=name_primary+event_date_time_local+venue_name+act_primary+ancestorGenreDescriptions+description
```

When I use a different url, e.g., "http://www.google.com/", the fetch succeeds.

When I paste the url string from the output into Chrome I get this response, which is the one I'm looking for:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":19,"params":{"fl":"name_primary event_date_time_local venue_name act_primary ancestorGenreDescriptions description","start":"0","q":"+event_date:[NOW TO NOW+1DAY]\r\n+ancestorGeoDescriptions:\"New York Metro\"\r\n+stubhubDocumentType:event +allowedViewingDomain:stubhub.com","wt":"json","version":"2.2","rows":"1"}},"response":{"numFound":26,"start":0,"docs":[{"act_primary":"Waka Flocka Flame","description":"Waka Flocka Flame Tickets (18+ Event)","event_date_time_local":"2015-04-20T20:00:00Z","name_primary":"Webster Hall","venue_name":"Webster Hall","ancestorGenreDescriptions":["All tickets","Concert tickets","Artists T - Z","Waka Flocka Flame Tickets"]}]}}
```

I hope I'm missing something simple. Any suggestions?

---

Update May 30, 2015

Anzel's suggestion of Apr 23 was correct. I need to add a user agent header. The one supplied by the AppEngine dev server is

```
AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
```

The one supplied by hosted AppEngine is

```
AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~MY_APP_ID)
```

The one supplied by requests.get() in pure Python (no AppEngine) on MacOS is

```
python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.3.0
```

When I switch in the Chrome user agent header all is well in pure Python. Stubhub must have changed this since I last tried it. Curious that they would require an interactive user agent for a service that emits JSON, but I'm happy they offer the service at all.

When I add that header in AppEngine, though, AppEngine prepends it to its own user-agent header. Stubhub then turns down the request.

So I've made some progress, but have not yet solved my problem.

FYI:

In AppEngine I supply the user agent like this:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=url,
    headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT_STRING}
)
```

This is a useful site for determining the user agent string your code or browser is sending:

http://myhttp.info/

Comment: Perhaps the site has now blocked any requests from appengine apps?

Comment: Thanks, Anzel! I suspect you are correct. I doubt stubhub would have blocked all AppEngine apps intentionally, but they might have done so accidentally. My next step ought to be to compare the headers that are being sent from AppEngine and from Chrome.

Comment: One more data point: When I send the URL using curl I receive an HTML error page suggesting that I call StubHub customer service.

Comment: oh one more thing have you tried changing the user agent header? they may just block request without a proper one

Answer (score 0):

I don't have priveledges yet to post comments, so here goes.

Look at the way you are entering the URL into the var 'url'. Is it already encoded as the error message says? I would try to make sure the url is a regular, non-encoded one, and test that, perhaps the library is re-encoding it again, causing problems. If you could give us more surrounding code, that may help in our diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, Andrew! You can see the contents of the 'url' variable in the output. It is encoded, but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be. Just in case I tried a simpler query which does not require encoding. The results are the same -- it works in a browser but produces a 416 error when invoked via urlfetch. This is what I used:"http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select/?q=&version=2.2&start=0&rows=1&wt=json&fl=name_primary+event_date_time_local+venue_name+act_primary+ancestorGenreDescriptions+description"